# Call useUpdateMany callback with data

Tags: react-admin

Reading the docs it seems that whenever I import `useUpdateMany` I already have to pass the data it's going to send. My question is, is it possible to pass the data on the callback?

I want to call the `updateMany` in a `handleSubmit` function, so I will only have the data when the function is called:

```
export const ChangeStatus = (props) => {
    const { record, version } = props;
    const { t } = useTranslation('admin');
    const classes = useStyles();
    const refresh = useRefresh();
    const notify = useNotify();
    const [componentStatus, setComponentStatus] = useState(null);
    const [updateMany, { loading, error }] = useUpdateMany('orders', props.selectedIds, {componentStatus });

    const defaultSubscription = {
        submitting: true,
        pristine: true,
        valid: true,
        invalid: true,
    };

    const handleSubmit = ({ status }) => {
        setComponentStatus({ status });
        updateMany();
        refresh();
    };

    return (
        <Form
            initialValues={record}
            subscription={defaultSubscription}
            key={version}
            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            render={(formProps) => (
                <form onSubmit={formProps.handleSubmit} className={classes.form}>
                    <SelectInput
                        label="Status"
                        variant="outlined"
                        source="status"
                        className={classes.selectField}
                        FormHelperTextProps={{ className: classes.selectHelperText }}
                        choices={[
                            { id: 'created', name: 'Created' },
                            { id: 'canceled', name: 'Canceled' },
                            { id: 'active', name: 'Active' },
                            { id: 'awaiting', name: 'Awaiting allocation' },
                            { id: 'processing', name: 'Processing' },
                            { id: 'review', name: 'Review' },
                            { id: 'completed', name: 'Completed' },
                        ]}
                    />
                    <Button variant="contained" color="secondary" type="submit" disabled={loading}>
                        {t('Confirm')}
                    </Button>
                </form>
            )}
        />
    );
};
```

Right now I'm updating a state and then calling the `updateMany`, but it would be much easier if I could call the `updateMany` passing the data:

```
const handleSubmit = ({ status }) =>
        updateMany({status});
};
```

Is it possible to do it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can override the params when calling `updateMany` function but you have to respect the mutation params format.

In your example you can do `updateMany({ payload: { data: { componentStatus } } });`

Indeed `useUpdateMany` call `useMutation` under the hood and this hook allow merge with `callTimeQuery`

You can find some references here :

https://marmelab.com/react-admin/Actions.html#usemutation-hook

> useMutation accepts a variant call where the parameters are passed to the callback instead of when calling the hook. Use this variant when some parameters are only known at call time.

https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/blob/bdf941315be7a2a35c8da7925a2a179dbcb607a1/packages/ra-core/src/dataProvider/useMutation.ts#L299

Also there is an issue wich foresees a more logical signature at call time : https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/issues/6047

(Update : And now this is merged for a future release:  https://github.com/marmelab/react-admin/pull/6168 )